# Replace Asterisk(*) with "anything" in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, variables, replace

I am having a tons of URL's in my database and want to filter them by user-defined string in format `something/*/something`, where `*` stands for "anything". So when user defines `checkout/*/complete`, it means it filters out url's like:

```
http://my_url.com/checkout/15/complete
http://my_url.com/checkout/85/complete
http://my_url.com/checkout/something/complete
http://my_url.com/super/checkout/something/complete
```

etc.

How do I do that in SQL? Or should I filter out all the results and use PHP to do the job?

My SQL request now is

```
SELECT * FROM custom_logs WHERE pn='$webPage' AND id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM custom_logs WHERE action_clicked_text LIKE '%{$text_value_active}%' GROUP BY token ) order by action_timestamp desc
```

This filters out all the log messages with user-defined text in column `action_clicked_text`, but uses `LIKE` statement, which will not work with `*` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `like`.  Either:

```
where url like '%checkout/%/complete%'
```

to get the urls that match he pattern.  Or:

```
where url not like '%checkout/%/complete%'
```

to get the other urls.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not know it could be so easy!